# streaming data service (web services)

Tags: java, web-services, amazon-web-services

I want to write webservices which will fetch data from a client (Android/Iphone) and push to a client (say website) real time. Android continuously sends data to the server, the same information should be shown on the website.

Data sent will be plain text file. My application on android will generate plain text every second, which will be sent to the server. The same plain text should be shown on the website.

```
-------            --------                  --------  
Android     ---->  Server      ------>       Website 
-------            --------                  --------
```

What technologies do you suggest to achieve real time results?

Comment: I suggest you to use Node.js

Comment: Please elaborate on the use case. You could do this with something like websockets but it is unclear how long you want to keep streaming or what you want to stream.

Comment: Its plain text, I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more info about the story, I can think of a number of suggestions and Im sure there are a number of ways to solve this.

**Case 1 : The message is sent unedited to the Website** - This is by far the simplest case, and you could use [Pusher.com](http://pusher.com) (or something like it) instead of writing your own server.  There is an android client available at [Android Client](http://pusher.com/docs/client_libraries#android-java).  But this would only work if you didn't want to manipulate the message between Android and the WebSite.  If you wanted the server to know about the messages (say for logging reasons), you could also have the server listen to the same channel as the website.

```
-------            --------                  --------  
Android     ---->  Pusher.com      ------>   Website 
-------            --------                  --------
```

**Case 2 : Your server needs to be in the middle or you need to own the middle man** -

This design could get tricker than you think.  It just depends on a number of factors.
For Example:

- Does your server need to scale horizontally or needs to be HA?
- Is the Android device talking to just one WebClient or publishing to many WebClients: 1 to 1 channels or pub/sub?
- How much server processing does it keep up with your inbound load.
- Do you need to retrieve messages produced while your WebClients are offline.
- What browser/android versions do you need to support.
- etc...

Based on these factors you could end up needing to support a design like this:

```
                                                         --------  
                              ---------- out-channel ->  WebClient0
                             |                           -------- 
-------                    --------                      --------  
Android  -- in-channel --> server1 ---- out-channel ->   WebClient1
-------               |    --------                      -------- 
                      |    --------                      --------  
                      \--> server2  ---- out-channel ->  WebClient2 
                           --------                      --------
```

Some basic frameworks to get you started:

1. [Pusher.com](http://pusher.com) - You could use two pusher channels with your servers in between the two inbound/outbound channels.
2. http://socket.io/  - This is a node.js module that's pretty easy to work with.  It includes a JavaScript library and would make a great choice for your outbound channels.  YFI: there exists a port of this project to Java/Netty too.
3. http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/ - This is a distributed queue provided by AWS. Because of cross origin policies, it doesn't work well with web browsers but Android can submit messages to it just fine.  So, it could work for the inbound channel.  Plus (like Pusher channels) SQS queues supports pub/sub, so you can publish the messages to all your servers.

There are a lot of frameworks out that deal with Realtime processing, but without knowing more I'm going to limit answer to these basics.

Comment: Thank you eSniff. These help me to get started. Yes, it should be the case2, there will be more than 1 webclient to pull the data from the server. All the data passed from Android to the server will be unedited and sent to web client. It will also be archived in the db.

Comment: Food for Thought: You could use pusher directly from Android (case 1), because your server is only archiving the messages not modifying them.  You could have Android push the message to a Channel-X, and have each WebClient listen to Channel-X.  Additionally have the server also listen to Channel-X so it can receive the messages for archiving.  So the WebClients would be using the messages to update their UIs and the server would be reading the messages to archive them.  Either way good luck!